# Is making a stock market related website haraam?

Tags: investment

I want to make a web app similar to Finviz.com, where the user can spend time and find information about the different companies and make personal decisions on further action thru screening.

But the concern is that a lot of the companies are dealing with riba or haraam industries. So will I be liable for the buying of such companies?
To put it in a different way is Google.com haraam because people use it for haraam things & its owner liable Islamically?

My web app won't show any personal opinion just fact and info available in open market, it doesn't even deal with buying and selling stocks or riba or any other haraam thing.
I'm confused, can I make a stock market web app as a Muslim?

Answer (score 0):

Selamun Aleykum,

As long as you provide a disclaimer or warning to your web audience that you don't endorse the business practices of your advertisers or web page participating companies you should be clear of any responsibility, liability, or culpability whether Islamic or otherwise.

For your Muslim web audience your disclaimer should contain references in Quran and Hadith regarding Riba, companies participating in Haram activities, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter what disclaimers you add. Selling rocket launchers with labels that say "by pulling the trigger you will cause death" does not excuse you from being an enabler. As a seller of weapons you will always be an enabler of death, and no fiqh, qran, logic or law can change that fact. Morality is innate and individually responsible.